# Cosmos db get one record of each partition key

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I have a container keeping some documents like:

```
{
        "id": "deece304-XXXXXXX-88e8-fcfc0c750e97",
        "log_VehicleId": 123,
        "latitude": -000.000,
        "longitude": 111.111,
        "_ts": 1593825193
}
```

my partition key is "log_VehicleId" i need a Cosmos SQl that gives me newset record of each partition

something like

```
Select top 1 from container c where c.log_VehicleId IN (123,234,312,123,873) 
order by c._ts DESC
```

would be fantastic to have LINQ equivalent of that too

so I will have newest record per "log_VehicleId"

thanks

Comment: Can you try something like:
SELECT
    MIN(c._ts) AS minTime
FROM c
GROUP BY c.log_VehicleId;

Comment: this take 25 seconds and 9000RU

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/sql-query-group-by):

> You currently cannot use GROUP BY with an ORDER BY clause but this is planned

So this is not supported now.You can vote and track this feature at [here](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/263030-azure-cosmos-db/suggestions/40820131-use-order-by-with-group-by).